# How to find items with no value for a property

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

With the [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org) (which I am new to), I am trying to find items that have no value for a property. In this case, I am looking for instances of (P31) humans (Q5) with no sex or gender (P21). My code is really basic:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?item wdt:P21 wd:Q6581072.
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
}
LIMIT 100
```

Line 3 restricts it to finding things with female as the sex or gender. **What could I replace it with that would make it only find things with no value for P21?** The guides that I've found and a bit of googling don't seem to have stuff about looking for things without a value for a given property.

Comment: `filter not exists{?item wdt:P31 ?val}` - although I'd think you mean *"no value for P21"* which is the gender property. Then `filter not exists{?item wdt:P21 ?val}`

Comment: @AKSW that would where the line `?item wd:P21 wd:Q6581072.` is, right? Or would it be somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: yes, just replace the existing triple pattern with the filter

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the comments...

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE
  {
    SERVICE wikibase:label
      { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?item wdt:P21 ?val }
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 
  }
LIMIT 100
```